# Replace last few digit to zero

Tags: php, math

What is the cleanest way to replace last few digit of a number to zero in PHP

Example of replace last three digit:

> 2746345 -> 2746000
>
> 67200 -> 67000

*Note : This is not rounding off*

Comment: `echo round(2746345, -3);` Reference PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: Thanks , i tried the mode too , the function always rounded up the result

Comment: I think you may have to mix division and `round` function with @Martin's answer instead of `floor`. Looks like the `mode` works only for decimal places.

Comment: @bansi Thanks for your reply , is there any hidden risk of only use floor to get rid of the digit? if no i think i will just stick with Martin solution , it is clean and easy to understand

Comment: the only risk you may face is `2746545` will be converted to `2746000`. If you expect this behavior @Martin's solution is the way to go. If you want `2746545` to be converted to `2747000`, just replace `floor` with `round`

Comment: Thats the behaviour I expected , I don't want the number rounding off , I will stick to Martin's solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One potential solution: divide by 1000, convert to a whole number, and then multiply by 1000 again.

```
$x = 2746345;
echo floor($x/1000)*1000; //prints 2746000
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, in your example you could also use `substr_replace` too. Example:

```
var_dump((int) substr_replace((string)67200, '000', -3, 3));// 67000
var_dump((int) substr_replace((string)2746345, '000', -3, 3)); // 2746000
```

Answer (score 0):

if

```
$number = 2746345;
```

Then you can use substr_replace like this

```
$replace = substr_replace($number, '000', -3, 3);
```